# decrease height and row spacing in vuetify form

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a form using `vuetify` which is basically, replicating this form.

[image]

I have tried to use vuetify grid and columns after a lot of tries I have got to this

[image]

I want to decrease the height of inputs as well as the spacing between rows.

Live code snippet https://codepen.io/ijunaid8088/pen/xxGZzGv

Comment: Is it possible to create a working example as from your code every things seems ok to me

Comment: Yes sure, I am adding one

Comment: my issue is I want to decrease the hight of inputs as well as I want to decrease the space up and below each row

Comment: I got you issue but need working example to fixed it, roughly i would say its the margin which causes the input section height

Comment: updated it with live link

Comment: The issue is you are using col and container for which there is padding coming, Are you allowed to use `flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override padding (and/or margin) values on the appropriate elements.

I'd recommend placing a `class` or `id` on a common ancestor of all the fields you want to modify (`inputs-container` class on `<v-container>`, in the example below), which allows you to only target the inputs inside that element, so you don't change all inputs in your app:

```scss
.inputs-container {
  .col-12 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .theme--light.v-input {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .v-input__slot {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

See it [working](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/MWwKXpZ).

Answer (score 3):

You can use "dense" to do that. Example shown below.

```
<v-text-field label="First name" outlined dense> </v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Best possible solution without changing default library styles

Add IP Camera

> 

```
    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="lastname"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="Last name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        label="E-mail"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="firstname"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="First name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="lastname"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="Last name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        label="E-mail"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">4</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
  </v-app>
</div>
//CSS
    .v-text-field {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is use py in each v-col:

with py="1" will use 4px, or another value that you want to bottom and top of the row.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#how-it-works