# Vuetify: how to sort out row spacing?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I do not understand why different Vuetify components have different spacing by default. I have tried and failed to change this spacing: there are suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223871/decrease-height-and-row-spacing-in-vuetify-form) but I cannot make them work in my case; they seem out-of-date or over-complex.
The result I have looks like this:

[image]

and I would just like to reduce the spaces between the form input rows, and increase the space bewteen the buttons and the form inputs. I can add spacing *between* the buttons by adding `class="mt-2">`

```
 <template>
  <div class="d-flex align-center flex-column">
    <v-card width="600">
      <v-card-title class="headline black" primary-title>
        choose one of the following:
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text class="pa-3">
        <v-form ref="rideForm">
          <v-row>
            <v-btn block variant="outlined" color="blue">choice 1</v-btn>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-btn block variant="outlined" color="blue">choice 2</v-btn>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-btn block variant="outlined" color="blue">choice 3</v-btn>
          </v-row>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-text-field label="Destination" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
              <v-text-field label="Distance" />
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="6">
              <v-text-field label="Date" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="3">
              <v-combobox label="Time: Hour"></v-combobox>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="3">
              <v-combobox label="Minute"></v-combobox>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="6">
              <v-text-field label="Starting At" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="3">
              <v-text-field label="Maximum" />
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="3">
              <v-text-field label="Speed" />
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn block color="blue" variant="outlined" class="mt-2"
                >Cancel</v-btn
              >
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
              <v-btn block color="blue" type="submit" class="mt-2">Save</v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>
```

so how to do this, and why are the defaults so different?
For a `v-list` I can add this css:

```
.v-list-item {
  min-height: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

but that seems not to work for other components.

Working demo [here on the Vuetify playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNrFVs1u2kAQfpWpL7RSDRSqHBBBilpVueREpR5KD+v1GFbZP+2ugSjKu3fWJg52SARKUE72zt83M56dz3/vE+/44Mra/rrEZJJMAyorWcDZQgNMc7EGLpn3l4skTwuJW2BSLHXKUQd0ECUpN7JUepFULuS0TjlzOWxEHlbkdzEcNrpGmwYRJDaxV8hyKTRCJhm/XSRgnVDM3dVmjTMAXxnjEQyZmgLCCqEwUpqN0MtJAzHYx3iOjNvQAFuWjveyq6wK4xQ4LEjtRI6/6NgyqYyc2bRElTALmiow/BbWzAmmA4UwZYiV5VQUNco4EmWyRIpItQiO8C3mS55tBJJ1Id4VdfQhqOMTUL1lHN0sanevx6RFuB1hJY4fPS0Eyhwky1BSZj/RB6FZEIZmFwbdUHGInsU6DUD4wDSn8o+KfkrzyTd2OE7wRWc2X8mHrvWJlT6CtO/InoXKTGa2DcRvoXAC16Z05FAHri3OiHkjdBkLOxXv7P2eB+ZowpZwFd637QewbthWqJL21Jlx5har632GgT6UwdOSae+TF3bObqmrkI4WSTccwOxHvI5yt4O6+jcugBdTDXcW6eTLTIk4CO0sZ3O2xkNb8dieRklkrCeea+iPPt8jJ+9kNasPiNbpbTrYI3s6eu6EDeAxlLYyFMoaF+A+kiE8QOGMgh79J/SiOXGx0T6A8ku4jBafe9dIVAx/jJP5p96XCFCHpGDJw9dk3B/3vyf1czRM/v0HZpVa1g==).

Comment: As a start, you probably want to put the buttons in v-cols and the rows into a v-container, otherwise the grid layout will not work. It seems odd to have three choice buttons as part of a form, my guess is that the buttons aren't part of the form, but rather users have four choices, i.e. click one of the buttons or fill out the form? In that case, it wouldn't make sense to set the same space between form elements as between buttons, but rather to highlight the four choices. Are you sure you just want to adjust the spacing?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure!  I've simplified things to show minimal code. In the real app, most of the form won't be dispalyed until one of the choices is made, and each choice results in a slightly different form to fill. But the buttons stay put in case the user made the wrong choice. I tried a `v-container` as per the answer in my link at the start of my post, but don't know what css to use in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vuetify 3 *Grid System* has a [props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#no-gutters) `no-gutters`.

> You can remove the negative margins from v-row and the padding from its direct v-col children using the no-gutters property.

Then, you can use class **margin and padding** to style its *width* and/or *height*.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thank you. Actually in my case I can't use `no gutters` because I have hints and rules on the fields (sorry I forgot to mention that, I was trying to simplify the demo!); these overlap with `no gutters` . But I have used your classes on the cols to improve things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> I would just like to reduce the spaces between the form input rows, and increase the space bewteen the buttons and the form inputs.

- Form inputs have a details area, where error messages and fill help goes. It adds a lot of white space when empty. Remove it using the [`hide-details`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-hide-details) prop to effectively reduce the height between form inputs.
- Similar as you describe, you can put a margin between button and inputs, for example by putting `mt-4` on the first v-row containing inputs.
- If you want it all evenly spaced, you probably want to put `size="x-large"` on the buttons, so that button height matches input height. Alternatively, `size="large"` matches `density="compact"` on the inputs.

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Though I still think something like [this](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) would work better for what you describe.

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion may be good. Having a  switch to show/hide the hints would be good for folk who have used it before and don't need help. I could then make the hints permanent. I'll think about it, thanks. (I don't like the 'extra large' buttons, though!)